# Evaluating $\int (x^6+x^3)\sqrt[3]{x^3+2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate:

$$\int (x^6+x^3)\sqrt[3]{x^3+2} \ \ dx$$

My solution:

$$\int (x^5+x^2)\sqrt[3]{x^6+2x^3} \ \ dx$$

Let $$(x^6+2x^3) = t^3 \ \  \text{and} \ \ (x^5+x^2) \ \ dx = \frac{1}{2}t^2 \ \ dt$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int t^2\cdot t \ \ dt = \frac{1}{2}.\frac{t^4}{4}+C $$

So $$\int (x^5+x^2)\sqrt[3]{x^6+2x^3} \ \ dx = \frac{1}{8}(x^6+2x^3)^{{4}/{3}}+C$$

Is that right? And is there a different way ?

Comment: Just a note: usually $\mathbb{C}$ denotes the complex numbers, while most use just C or K to indicate a constant for integrals.

Comment: Looks right to me. You can verify it by differentiating your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $t$ stuff is not necessary. You can directly let $u=x^6+2x^3$. Then $(x^5+x^2)\,dx=\frac{1}{6}\,du$. But the initial step was the key one.

Comment: Nice trick ,but i did it in the solution

Comment: As is often the case, I didn't read, it is usually easier to solve.